# wavelet package Inverse DWT fails to reconstruct series?

Tags: r, wavelet

I'm using the [wavelets](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wavelets/wavelets.pdf) package, and noticed that when I try

```
library("wavelets")
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- idwt(dwt(x))
plot(x, y)
```

the reconstruction `y` is apparently not equal to the original `x`.

Is this to be expected?

For some context, I'm trying to do a (regularized) logistic regression using the wavelet transforms of a bunch of series. I then want to map the regression coefficient back into the original time series space, to see which time points were used in the discrimination.

But I can't seem to even reconstruct the original series. I might be completely misunderstanding things, can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: It works with `y <- idwt(dwt(x, n.levels=3, boundary="reflection", fast=FALSE))`, for example (see `?dwt`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the help file `?dwt`, you can modify your script, such as:

```
library(wavelets)
set.seed(42)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- idwt(dwt(x, n.levels=3, boundary="reflection", fast=FALSE))
plot(x, y)
abline(0,1)
```

[image]